# How to get combo value dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a `combobox` dynamically. Right now I am using `option` tag and placing in side `select` tag.

```
    <div>
              <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" tabindex="4">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="United States">United States</option>
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
              </select>
            </div>
```

How can I make it dynamically. I can take it from JSON. How and where to write function in script. 
1. How to fetch data from url and place into combo values.
I want into plain javascript.

This is my JSON data

```
[
    {
        ID : 0,
        VALUE : "United State"
    },{
        ID : 1,
        VALUE : "United Kingdom"
    },{
        ID : 2,
        VALUE : "Afghanistan"
    },{
        ID : 3,
        VALUE : "Aland Islands"
    },{
        ID : 4,
        VALUE : "Albania"
    }
]
```

Update Code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Chosen: A jQuery Plugin by Harvest to Tame Unwieldy Select Boxes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="docsupport/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="docsupport/prism.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="chosen.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; style-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:">
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="content">
        <div class="side-by-side clearfix">
        <div class="side-by-side clearfix">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <div>
              <select id="choose" data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" tabindex="4">
                <option value=""></option>

              </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
<script>
var jsonc = [
    {
        ID : 0,
        VALUE : "United State"
    },{
        ID : 1,
        VALUE : "United Kingdom"
    },{
        ID : 2,
        VALUE : "Afghanistan"
    },{
        ID : 3,
        VALUE : "Aland Islands"
    },{
        ID : 4,
        VALUE : "Albania"
    }
];

var new_opt="";
for(i=0;i<jsonc.length;i++)
{


   new_opt+='<option value="'+jsonc[i]['VALUE']+'">'+jsonc[i]['VALUE']+'</option>';
}

document.getElementById('choose').innerHTML =new_opt;
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like home work problem.

Comment: did you read about ajax? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Will appreciate if I get any help.

Comment: Narrow down your problem. What specific issue are you having? Fetching data from somewhere (where)? Choosing between JSON and XML? Parsing JSON or XML? Extracting data from the parsed response? Populating the select element once you've done that?

Comment: @JurijJazdanov yes.. but I don't wann to use jquery.

Comment: A combobox is a UI control that is a combination (hence the name) of a drop down menu (which is what you get with a select in HTML) and a text input (an input of type text). HTML doesn't have any native controls that are represented as comboboxes. You've got a select element.

Comment: I think he just wants to render option tags given that data is already available. But still too vague.

Comment: @dfsq Yes, I want to render the data through JSON.

Comment: So post what data you are dealing with.

Comment: `data.forEach(option => select.add(new Option(option.VALUE, option.ID))})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I added id attribute to the select box `id="choose"`

```js
var jsonc = [
    {
        ID : 0,
        VALUE : "United State"
    },{
        ID : 1,
        VALUE : "United Kingdom"
    },{
        ID : 2,
        VALUE : "Afghanistan"
    },{
        ID : 3,
        VALUE : "Aland Islands"
    },{
        ID : 4,
        VALUE : "Albania"
    }
];

var new_opt="";
for(i=0;i<jsonc.length;i++)
{


   new_opt+='<option value="'+jsonc[i]['VALUE']+'">'+jsonc[i]['VALUE']+'</option>';
}

document.getElementById('choose').innerHTML =new_opt;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
              <select id="choose" data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" tabindex="4">
                <option value=""></option>
                
              </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: Do I need to write an function inside an script tag

Comment: jquery included twice remove one and remove this line it will work <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; style-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:"> @shankysingh

Comment: Thank you work like a charm. So I need to use jquery. Without that it is not possible is it /

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference .@shankysingh

Answer (score 1):

With your JSON data and the attribute `id="choose"` you can iterate over the `jsonc` array and add new options like this:

```js
var jsonc = [{ID: 0,VALUE: "United State"}, {ID: 1,VALUE: "United Kingdom"}, {ID: 2,VALUE: "Afghanistan"}, {ID: 3,VALUE: "Aland Islands"}, {ID: 4,VALUE: "Albania"}],
    selectBox = document.getElementById('choose');

jsonc.forEach(function (elem) {
  selectBox.options.add(new Option(elem.VALUE, elem.ID));
});
```

```html
<select id="choose">
  <option value="">Choose a Country...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. DO I need to write in a `some function` under script tag and then I need to called that function.